# file_get_contents seems to add extra returns to the data

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Hi I am trying to run a simple php file open, replace, and save. Here is my code:

```
//open file and get data
$data = file_get_contents("input.xml");

// do tag replacements or whatever you want
$data = str_replace("<Property>", "<item>", $data);
$data = str_replace("</Property>", "</item>", $data);

//save it back:
file_put_contents("output.xml", $data);
```

My file opens, does the replace, and saves the file. But when I opened the file I noticed that there was an extra line return after every item that previously had only one line return.

I tested printing out the data directly to my browser and noticed that the extra line breaks are being introduced in `file_get_contents`, not when writing back to the new file.

Anyone have any idea how to prevent these extra line returns from being introduced in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: Browser debugging is not the most reliable method to detect the presence of whitespace characters. Try `urlencode()` instead - it isn't designed for this purpose, but non-ascii printable characters will be encoded with their hex values.

Comment: possibly a problem with CRLF vs LF, windows vs unix line breaks.

Comment: Seems like an issue with `\n` and `\r\n` linebreaks.

Comment: hm..my system is unix, but the file I am getting may be from windows, are you saying I should convert the file first? I assume there is some php command to allow me to do this?

Comment: You could also do a `str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $data);`

Comment: That was it guys, thanks, I just made the following addition:

`// fix line endings
$data = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to the commenters, that was an easier fix than I thought:

I just made the following addition:

```
// fix line endings 
$data = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $data);
```

Comment: this will remove new line that may be present in the file. (I guess it probably don't apply to your case, but might apply to other)

the rtrim($content, "\n") way will only remove the last char

Answer (score 3):

file_get_contents adds newline at the end of returned string.
This helped me to remove newline:

`$content = trim($content, "\r\n");`

Comment: This will also remove new lines that may be at the beginning of the file, rtrim is better.

Answer (score 1):

using **[rtrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)** is a better solution as it will only remove "\n" char at the end of the content (that one that has been added by file_get_contents()).

```
$content = rtrim($content, "\r\n");
```

**str_replace** or **trim** may alter the file content if it contains new line.